# Understanding the order of properties execution in Vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm creating a simple Vuejs div component (to show a specific value) which needs to receive: a `lists`, a `placeholder` and a `value` as props. What I'm trying to do is displaying the value with the data from my database, if the user picks a new value from the `lists`, it should take that new value and display it. However, if the user never picks a new value and the data from the database is empty, it should display the `placeholder`.

So I have used `filters` to achieve this. However, it outputs an error: `"Cannot read property 'lists' of undefined"`, which comes from the `filters` (I know because it outputs no error if I comment out the `filters`). When I changed the `filter` to this:

```
  filters: {
    placeholderFilter () {
      return this.placeholderText || this.placeholder
    }
  }
```

It says:"`"Cannot read property 'placeholderText' of undefined"`". So I was wondering if the filters properties executed before the `data` and `props` properties. What is the execution order of them? I have attached some of the relevant code down below. Anyway, If you could come up with a better way to achieve this. I would appreciate it!

Here is my component:

```
<template>
<div>{{ placeholderText | placeholderFilter }}</div>
<li @click="pickItem(index)" v-for="(list,index) in lists" :key="index">{{ list }}</li>
</template>

<script>

export default {
  props: {
    lists: {
      type: Array,
      required: true
    },
    value: {
      type: [String, Number],
      default: ''
    },
    placeholder: {
      type: String,
      default: ''
    }
  },
  data () {
    return {
      selected: -1,
      placeholderText: this.value || this.placeholder
    }
  },
  methods: {
    pickItem (index) {
      this.selected = index
    }
  },
  filters: {
    placeholderFilter () {
      return this.lists[this.selected] || this.placeholderText || this.placeholder
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

And this is where I use it:

```
<my-component 
    placeholder="Please type something" 
    value="Data from database" 
    lists="['option1','option2','option3']"
>
</my-component>
```

Comment: I would just use a computed property in this case. Filters are for actually for transforming texts. This placeholder text is a clearly Computed Property for me. Try using a computed property instead of a filter.

Comment: Thank you. I have thought about it. I'll try to go back to computed property

Comment: Anyway, I'm still trying to understand what is going on under the hood in Vuejs. It doesn't make sense to me, the `props` property should be executed first from what I understand, where the `lists` should be defined before going to `filters`

Comment: As mentioned below, it's just a simple method. Remember filters are reusable. If they bound to instance data, they aren't reusable. So cannot be used this way.

Answer (score 1):

Filters aren't bound to the component instance, so they simply don't have access to it through the `this` keyword. They are meant to always be passed a parameter and to return a transformed version of that parameter. So in other words, they're just methods. They were removed in Vue 3 entirely probably for that reason.

And yeah, what you're looking for here is a computed!